# How to get current coordinates/location in android

Tags: android, gps, coordinates, android-gps

I've been working on trying to **get the current location** in **android** since several days but I didn't find a solution yet.

I know there are similar topics regarding this but in my case the code it didn't work. Is there anyone who has already solved this issue and can help me?

I add some tests I did.
Here's the GPS Tracker class.

```
package utility;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;

public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {


    private final Context mContext;

    // flag for GPS status
    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

    // flag for network status
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

    // flag for GPS status
    boolean canGetLocation = false;

    Location location; // location
    double latitude; // latitude
    double longitude; // longitude

    // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 1; // 10 meters

    // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

    // Declaring a Location Manager
    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    public GPSTracker(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        getLocation();
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                    .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // getting GPS status
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            // getting network status
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                // no network provider is enabled
            } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;
                // First get location from Network Provider
                if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                    try {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    } catch (SecurityException e) {

                    }
                    Log.d("Network", "Network");
                    if (locationManager != null) {

                        try {
                            location = locationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        } catch (SecurityException e) {

                        }

                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
                // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    if (location == null) {

                        try {
                            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                    MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                    MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                            Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                            if (locationManager != null) {
                                location = locationManager
                                        .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                                if (location != null) {
                                    latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                    longitude = location.getLongitude();
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (SecurityException s) {

                        }

                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return location;
    }

    /**
     * Stop using GPS listener
     * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
     */
    public void stopUsingGPS() {
        if (locationManager != null) {
            try {
                locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
            } catch (SecurityException e) {

            }

        }
    }

    /**
     * Function to get latitude
     */
    public double getLatitude() {
        if (location != null) {
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }

        // return latitude
        return latitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to get longitude
     */
    public double getLongitude() {
        if (location != null) {
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }

        // return longitude
        return longitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public boolean canGetLocation() {
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }

    /**
     * Function to show settings alert dialog
     * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
     */
    public void showSettingsAlert() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS Settings");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not active. Do you want to open?");

        // On pressing Settings button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        // on pressing cancel button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

And I instantiated this class in my activity, as follows:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import utility.GPSTracker;


public class AroundMeActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_around_me);

        TextView location_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.location_text);

        GPSTracker gps;
        double latitude = 0.0;
        double longitude = 0.0;

        gps = new GPSTracker(AroundMeActivity.this);

        // check if GPS enabled
        if(gps.canGetLocation())
        {
            latitude = gps.getLatitude();
            longitude = gps.getLongitude();
        }
        else
        {
            gps.showSettingsAlert();
        }

        location_text.setText(latitude + " " + longitude);

    }
}
```

The results is 0.0 for both latitude and longitude.

Thank you in advance guys!!!

Comment: The Fused Location Provider is the recommended way, unless you have some reason to avoid Google Play Services. (Like wanting your app. to work in China.) You could follow the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html) and [example in the Documentation section](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/1837/location#t=201612041037447620643). Just notice that `getLastLocation()` may return `null` or an old and irrelevant location so it's better to request updates. You can always stop them if you don't need continuous updates.

Comment: That's not what I was looking for. It calculates location updates starting from a current location, but I'd need to retrieve the current coordinates in a precise instant.

Answer (score 0):

Use android [LocationMannager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html)

Checkout androidhive tutorial about [Android GPS, Location Manager](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/) to get started

Comment: Yes, I checked androidhive as first tutorial and I followed it step by step but it didn't work.

Comment: Well, that's because it's a bad tutorial. Just ignore it. (More details are [in this blog post](http://gabesechansoftware.com/location-tracking/).

Comment: I will check out both of them again. Has anyone of you tried to use some of that code?

Comment: Not true, both of them are the same with very minor differeces! @MarkusKauppinen

Comment: The blog post first shows the code (like on androidhive) that it talks about and after that points out the problems with it. And finally shows a better solution.

Comment: Ok @MarkusKauppinen, I've just read the blog post and implemented all the classes, activity and interface needed. BUT there are no instructions on how to use them.

Comment: Do you add a sample code on how to retrieve the current GPS location?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a great library, very easy to use and lightweight: https://github.com/mrmans0n/smart-location-lib

Just compile it with gradle and thats' it.

Comment: The guide is nice, but after compiling it the app crashes. Do you have a sample code I can use in my app just to test how to retrieve the current gps coordinates?

Comment: No, unfortunately I don't have anymore, I've used it in the past. But is should be pretty simple, though I can't help with the integration. Ask them on their github repository.